# SSRS Sort matrix by column name

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Let's say I have table with some rows and columns in sql. Columns are (id, column1,column2,column3),
I did unpivot. And got dataset in ssrs like : Key,ColumnName,ColumnValue. I created matrix like below structure:

```
----------------------
Key     | ColumnName
----------------------
[Key]   | [ColumnValue]
------------------------
```

Question: How I can do something like: "Order by Column2" (or order by multiple column2,Column3) in matrix in SSRS? Where I need mention to sort by certain column name?

Comment: [Key] column in the matrix is [Id] from the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe question was not clear enough. But with help of @Alan I found solution that works for me perfect.
So if we want to get like "Order by Column1" then after unpivot Put your dataset in the matrixes. Go the the matrix which you want to Sort by specific column (in my case column1)
Row group properties---->Sorting----> Add---> Expression:

`MAX( IIF(Fields!ColumnName.Value="Column1",Fields!ColumnValue.Value,Nothing) )`

and if you want to ad also Column2 to this matrix to sort, just after set 1st expression in the same window click --->add---> expression----> same query but with your column name (ex. Column2).

Hope this will help to some one.

Answer (score 1):

I've generated some test data and I am assuming your unpivoted data looks something along these lines.

### In the Dataset Query

If so you could pass a sort column name in as a parameter from SSRS. If you do this you will not need to declare the variable in your dataset query but I have declare and set it's value for this example.

```
CREATE TABLE #t (KeyID int, ColName varchar(20), ColValue int)
INSERT INTO #t VALUES
(1, 'Price',        10),
(1, 'Quantity',     10),
(1, 'Value',        100),
(2, 'Price',        20),
(2, 'Quantity',     2),
(2, 'Value',        40),
(3, 'Price',        30),
(3, 'Quantity',     1),
(3, 'Value',        30)

DECLARE @SortCol varchar(20) = 'Quantity'

SELECT 
    t.*, s.SortBy
    FROM #t t
        JOIN (SELECT KeyID, SUM(ColValue) AS SortBy FROM #t WHERE ColName = @SortCol GROUP BY KeyID) s 
            ON t.KeyID = s.KeyID
    ORDER BY SortBy desc
```

This will give you the following results.

[image]

You don't actually need the `ORDER BY` clause as you will be sorting this in SSRS, in SSRS you can order the rows or rowgroups by the `SortBy` field.

### Using SSRS Expressions

If you want to use only SSRS expression then, using the same sample data as above (but without the additional sort column) ...

Create a new dataset (e.g. `dsCols`) that contains a list of `ColName` e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColName FROM #t ORDER BY ColName
```

Create a parameter called `SortCol`

In the parameter properties, choose AVailable Values "Get values from a query" and select `dsCols`.  Set both the value and label as the `ColName` field.

Now, in your matrix, select the rowgroup (in my example it's called `KeyID`)

Go to "Sorting" tab...

[image]

Set the sort expression to

```
=SUM
   (
    IIF(Fields!ColName.Value = Parameters!SortCol.Value, 
        Fields!ColValue.Value, 
        NOTHING)
   )
```

Set the order "A to Z" or "Z to A" as required.

Now when you run the report, you can choose which column, to sort by...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you @alan. Yeah I want to do it in SSRS, not in SQL query. I have matrix in SSRS and I want to sort there based on column.

Comment: This would give you data in the correct format to put in a matrix as I explained. If you want to do this purely in SSRS - I would recommend against that unless you are forced to - then you will have to use an expression that replicates the functionality above, i.e. sort using (abbreviated) `SUM(IIF(ColName=@SortCol,ColValue,0))`

Comment: Yeah I have dynamic sql, it's not just 1 table. that's why just for some my tabs(matrix) I want to do "sort" in SSRS level. I did some that kind of expression in the "column group" - Sorting settings , but seems didn't work. Where I have to use that expression in SSRS? It what settings?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a solution that uses SSRS expressions only for sorting.

Comment: I wanted to do it without extra filter on my report. I have multiple matrixes and each need to be sorted by different columns. I've tried in Row Group Properties --->Sorting----> Expression :  SUM(IIF(ColumnName="Column1",ColumnValue,0)), but it didn't work. Also I've tried COUNT instead of SUM. No luck so far... Thanks

Comment: You need to clearly explain this in your question. Your question was very simple and I provided solutions which appear to have answered what you asked for (even if that was not what you actually wanted). If you feel my answers have answered your original question, then mark it as accepted and then create a new question with all the relevant details included. You will never get a satisfactory answer if you do not ask clear questions

Comment: Yes you probably right. I will create new detailed question. Thanks @alan

Comment: This I hope more detailed question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67420938/sort-by-specific-column-name-matrix-in-ssrs